# MATCH function in a multi dimensional array

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to extract the row location of a cell with the minimum value in a range which consists of 2 different columns that are not adjacent. It seems MATCH function does not allow the use of more than one dimensional arrays. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered writing a macro?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to keep it free from macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try an array formula like this

`=MIN(IF(IF({1,0},A1:A100,D1:D100)=MIN(A1:A100,D1:D100),ROW(A1:A100)-ROW(A1)+1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

assuming that your data is in `A1:A100` and `D1:D100`

If Min value is found in A8 (or D8) the formula will return 8

Comment: just out of curiosity, can this method be extended to finding the column location, as well? (e.g. to return 1 or 4 for columns A and D)